# How can I build for amd 64 using clang?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, x86-64, cross-compiling

I am trying to build an application for amd64 using clang on mac os. Here is the clang information:

```
aurelie@MacBook-Pro-de-aurelie ~/D/p/U/a/par2cmdline-0.3a (master) [2]> clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
aurelie@MacBook-Pro-de-aurelie ~/D/p/U/a/par2cmdline-0.3a (master)>
```

Here are my clang arguments:

```
-g -O2
```

---

While looking for a solution online I came across an solution which required me to put a line that would make clang use build for amd 64. it didn't met my requirements as I use make as build system.

---

The second thing I tried was to use the argument `-march`. I used it like that: `-march=64`.

I expect to be able to build my app for amd 64 instead of arm.

Comment: Look at `xcrun --show-sdk-path` and specific clang `-isysroot`.

Comment: what do i need to look at it

Comment: Specific - specify. Auto completion is not very smart.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Read the compiler documentation to see a list of supported targets. `64` all on its own is not a valid target.

Comment: Alright. I looked up at clang docs. THey instructed me to use `x86_64`. It did not work. Here is the  compiler output: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`